# Are trace function embedded in $L^\infty$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, trace

Consider a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ with a Lipschitz boundary (could also be a smooth boundary). Is the trace space $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ embedded in $L^\infty(\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: No, it isn't. Consider the Sobolev embedding with dimension $d-1$, summability exponent $p=2$ and smoothness exponent $1/2$. It does not give $L^\infty$. And Sobolev embedding is sharp.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me a good reference for the Sobolev embedding with broken smoothness exponent?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make a link in comment so I write it here, you don't need to take this as an answer.

@Fundamental's answer is good enough, the answer is no. If you are looking for good reference for Sobolev embedding, especially focus on Trace operator, I would recommend you read [Leoni](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686)'s book, it explains embedding and trace in a very details way.

Comment: `[text](url)` work in comments [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686).

Comment: @Fundamental I see, thank you!